# How do I connect to a Webmatrix database in Umbraco?

Tags: sql, database, content-management-system, umbraco, webmatrix

The title pretty much lists out the question I want to ask.

I've only started working with Umbraco four days ago (as a part of a project I'm working on during my internship), and I need to create an online webshop. I'm still just working on getting used to this software, but there is one question which I haven't been able to find an answer for: How do I link a database made in WebMatrix to my website in Umbraco?

Keep in mind, I am not able to use .net files because I have no access to Microsoft Virtual PC. The computer I'm assigned to work on has already had a Trial version in the past, inserting a new Trial code does not work, and the company will not refund me buying the software.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have assess to web.config and the "bin" folder of the solution? If so, add webmatrix.data.dll to your bin and add a connection string to your web.config file to reference your db.

Then create a macro(razor) in the development section, import the webmatrix namespace ( @using webmatrix.data) then you can query like so:

```
var db = Database.Open("mydatabaseinconnectionstring");
var query = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Condition";

foreach(var item in db.Query(query)){
//write out put here

Response.Write(@item.propertyValueFromDb);

}
```

Comment: It is also advisable to do a db.Close(); once finished executing!